# How to use nodejs RESTful api to query from multiple collections?

Tags: node.js, rest, api

nodejs noobie here,

I have created nodejs RESTful api for fetching data from three different collections. Here is the article which helped me [nodejs api in 10 minutes](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd)

After creating APIs, I am able to hit the APIs through postman and get data there. Now I wish to move on to next step of querying records from multiple collections

**Server.js**

```
    var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),

  port = process.env.PORT ||3000,
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  menu = require('./app/api/bestseller_books/models/bestsellerBooksModel'),
    admin = require('./app/api/admin/models/adminModel'),
    test = require('./app/api/test/models/testModel'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  var cors = require('cors');


// mongoose instance connection url connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/takebook', { useMongoClient: true }); 
/*mongoose.model('menu', new Schema({ title: String, id: Number }));*/

var menu = mongoose.model('bestseller_books');
var test = mongoose.model('test');
var admin = mongoose.model('admin');
var routes = require('./app/api/bestseller_books/routes/bestsellerBooksRoutes'); 
var routes2 = require('./app/api/admin/routes/adminRoutes');
var routes3 = require('./app/api/test/routes/testRoutes');


menu.find({}, function(err, data) { console.log(err, data.length); });


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

routes(app); //register the route
/*routes2(app);
routes3(app);*/


app.listen(port);
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.status(404).send({url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'})
});

console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

**bestsellerbooks controller**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  menu = mongoose.model('bestseller_books');

exports.list_all_menus = function(req, res) {
  menu.find({}, function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(menu);
    console.log(res);
  });
};

exports.create_a_menu = function(req, res) {
  var new_menu = new menu(req.body);
  new_menu.save(function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(menu);
  });
};


exports.read_a_menu = function(req, res) {
  menu.findById(req.params.menuId, function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(menu);
  });
};


exports.update_a_menu = function(req, res) {
  menu.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.menuId}, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(menu);
  });
};


exports.delete_a_menu = function(req, res) {
  menu.remove({
    _id: req.params.menuId
  }, function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: 'bestseller_books successfully deleted' });
  });
};
```

My questions are :

1. Do I have to create new set of models, controllers and routes for
   each API?
2. Looking at the server.js, is this the best practice of
   setting up API routes?
3. What is the use of `create_a_menu` methods
   mentioned in API controllers, if I have to hit API in this format:

   ```
   app.controller('booklister', ['$http', function($http) {
   var self = this;
   $http.get('http://localhost:3000/bestseller_books')
   .then(function(response) 
   {
         /*$('.fa-refresh').hide();*/
         self.items = response.data;
       }, function(errResponse) {
         /*$('.fa-refresh').show();*/
         console.error('Service Error while fetching books' + errResponse);
       });
   ```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to use nodejs api for querying two different collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create more from everything.
New model, new schema, new Bl layer, new route that take care for that new collection.

For  example:

In yore dotsModel.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var DotsSchema = new Schema({

    x: {
        type: Number
    },
    y: {
        type: Number
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Dots', DotsSchema);
```

In youre dotsController.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Dots = mongoose.model('Dots')

exports.get_all_dots = function (req, res) {
    Dots.find({}, function (err, task) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(task);
    });
};
```

And in your dotsRoutes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var todoList = require('../controllers/ dotsController.js:');

app.route('/dots')
    .get(todoList.get_all_dots);
```

## Note:

The article you read is short and he touch really briefly on each topic, it's highly recommended to take another course, much longer, and take the time to learn each part of your application, and what node capable of.

Comment: I already have the same sort of code, but I want to fetch records in my web page, which I don't see.

Comment: You asked about nodejs or about calling your node api from the client side?

Comment: Calling nodejs api from client side. Works well on Postman but now want to put it to real use: to render records in HTML.

Comment: Your question really did not address this issue. And for your question - most often access APIs created by AJAX request. If you do not know how to do it - you'll have to learn about it before you ask again

Comment: Ok, this question I asked was like years ago when I was new to nodejs. But yeah, your answer counts as I realized my mistake. I was thinking that one server.js will have routes for two collections, model for two collections etc.